# angularjs: inside trustAsHtml why ng-event is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was using trustAsHtml and ng-bind-html for long time so I have idea how to use them.

Recently I was trying to include some ng-event on my html code which I was collection through http request and displaying through ng-bind-html.

But the problem is that its not initiating any event. The code is like this, Collecting data

```
    $http({
        method: "POST", url: 'target url',
        data: {tardata: data},
        header: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.mydata = data;
    });
```

Next I am changing some of the mydata value with text replace function

```
txt = txt.replace(key[a], '<b ng-mouseover="displayDefin('value')" >'+value+'</b>');
```

As you can see i used ng-mouseover but it was not initiating. I my page source code I checked that the content was changed with ng-mouseover event.
I am confused if its possible or not.

If not and If you know any other alternative method in angularjs please suggest me.

Comment: I solved it in different way. I use javascript event to call angular method. It works now. Also I am waiting if anyone can give me better solution in angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

If you like push html , you can :

```
var data = '<p>Hola</p>';
$scope.respuesta= $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
```

and after in the html

```
<div ng-bind-html="respuesta"></div>
```

and you should declare $sce in you controller .

Now you can embed the ng-mouseover in the html

Comment: According to your suggestion I tried this way  `app.controller('indexcontroll', ['$scope','$http', '$window', '$sce', function($scope, $http, $window, $sce){
    $scope.testTag = '<p ng-mouseover="displayDefin(3)">This is a test</p>';
    $scope.respuesta= $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.testTag);` and `<div ng-bind-html="respuesta"></div>`  but its not working.

Comment: What it is the problem now ? you can display the html ?

Comment: I was expecting it will work with the event. ng-mouseover. Its not working.